# android displaying list of list in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have a list of list of items that I would like to display in android
my items looks as below

```
Topic 1
  . SubTopic 1
  . SubTopic 2
  . SubTopic 3
  . SubTopic 4

Topic 2
  . SubTopic 5
  . SubTopic 6
  . SubTopic 7

Topic 3
  . SubTopic 8
  . SubTopic 9
  . SubTopic 10
  . SubTopic 11
  . SubTopic 12

//etc
```

This needs to be displayed in one activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I thought of creating the item that gets attached to the above recycler view with a textview for Topic and a recyclerview for the list of subtopics and have 2 adapters for both the recyclerview.

Is there any better way of doing this or nested recyclerview is the only way?

Comment: create recyclerview within a recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

you can also make complicated adapter and hold all this nested logic inside.
I think, this [link](https://oozou.com/blog/implementing-a-nested-recyclerview-in-android-with-mergeadapter-57) should help you with this problem.